# Why can't I access the excel file in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to use some data that I have in an excel file. However, I'm getting an error saying that it doesn't find the file. I've looked up and the directory and the file name are correct, What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

print(os.getcwd())

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/Eder/Desktop/TFG/Data/Interpolation_sample.xlsx',
                   index_col =0,parse_dates=True, sheet_name='sheet3')
```

And the answer from the console:

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/Eder/untitled0.py')
C:\Users\Eder\Desktop\TFG\Data
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Eder\untitled0.py", line 14, in <module>
    index_col =0,parse_dates=True, sheet_name='sheet3')

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1072, in __init__
    content=path_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 950, in inspect_excel_format
    content_or_path, "rb", storage_options=storage_options, is_text=False

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 651, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Eder\\Desktop\\TFG\\Data\\Interpolation_sample.xlsx'
```

Comment: If `os.path.exists(r'C:/Users/Eder/Desktop/TFG/Data/Interpolation_sample.xlsx')` returns `False` then double-check your paths. Perhaps the filename extension is different.

Comment: are you sure that the file with the exact name exists in the Data directory? "Interpolation_sample.xlsx"

Comment: Have you tried, ```xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)```. And then ```dfs = {sheet_name: xl_file.parse(sheet_name) 
          for sheet_name in xl_file.sheet_names}```

Comment: I've done what @JustinEzequiel said and the console returns the path where the python file is saved (not the excel file). I've also what you said and I got the same error.

Comment: How would [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) (which returns `True` or `False`) like I suggested you check, return "the path where the python file is saved (not the excel file)"? I suspect it's a PEBKAC issue.

Comment: I was wrong. When I run `os.path.exists(r'C:/Users/Eder/Desktop/TFG/Data/Interpolation_sample.xlsx')` it doesn't return anything, it just runs the cell and doesn't do anything. The console shows `In [100]: runcell(3, 'C:/Users/Eder/Desktop/TFG/Python saves/interpolation sample.py')`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to solve the problem. I just changed the name of the file from 'Interpolation_sample' to 'Interpolation sample'. I don't know why, but the underscore in the file name is what was causing this error.